# OpenApi for php doesn't render enum values correctly

Tags: php, swagger-ui, openapi

I am building some documentation using OpenApi and Swagger, but I am unable to test it because of a js error.

I want to define a parameter that will accept specific values so I added `enum` in the `schema` attribute.
I am defining the `orderBy` parameter in a `GET` request like this

```
*     @OA\Parameter(in="query", name="orderBy", required=false, allowEmptyValue=true, description="Sort type of results", examples={"asc", "desc"}, schema={"type": "string", "enum": {"asc", "desc"}, "default": "asc"})
```

When the documentation is generated I am getting the error below
[image]

Developer tools

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removed `examples` attribute and it rendered properly.

```
*     @OA\Parameter(in="query", name="orderBy", required=false, allowEmptyValue=true, description="Sort type of results", examples={"asc", "desc"}, schema={"type": "string", "enum": {"asc", "desc"}, "default": "asc"})
```